# Chromium based Opera: Modify pages after by javascript (as possible with the old Opera)

Tags: javascript, opera

My question is twofold:

1) is it possible at all

2) if yes,

```
   how

 else 

   any suggestions
```

After several hours of searching through the web I was not able to find a solution.

So let me introduce my intention:

With the 12.x Opera it was possible to perform changes to pages after load via an local javascript-file. So it was possible to e.g. set different colors, perform some settings, mybe also modify the presentation to my requirements.

I know something can be done by extensions, but not everything as it seems.

I would like to set some input values after page load for a query. The underlying HTML is in  principle as follows:

```
<html>
  <head>
   ....
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="Control">
        <button id="Btn" class="...."  title=".....">
         <span class=".....">BtnTxt</span>
        </button>
        <select id="loopCount">
         <option value="1" selected="selected">AAAA</option>
         <option value="2">BBBB</option>
         <option value="3">CCCC</option>
        </select>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I would like to set loopCount to option 3 and executed the standard js.

Just to clearify again, the page is external and I want to change the values after page load. I have no access to the original page.

Thanks for any help/suggestions.

Comment: In fact extensions are more powerful than userscripts, and can do everything those could before. IIRC, there are extensions to run userscripts in Chromium. Have you tried any of them?

Comment: Thank you the hint with the extensions. This solved my issue.
There are several extensions as you said.
My solution for those who have a similar issue:
I have used [Scripter] (https://addons.opera.com/de/extensions/details/scripter-script-includer/?display=en)  as it allows to specify when the script should fire.
For those who are somehat novice like I am to avoid long testing:
It - seems logical - that the scripts are run before any initiation is done. This means if the page uses jQuery this can be used, as initiation is executed after the injected code. (Maybe someone can confirm this.)

Answer (score 0):

My solution for those who have a similar issue: 
I have used [Scripter](https://addons.opera.com/de/extensions/details/scripter-script-includer/?display=en) as it allows to specify when the script should fire. For those who are somehat novice to Javascript, like I am, to avoid long testing cycles: It - seems logical - that the scripts are executed before any initiation is done. That means if the page uses jQuery this can not be used, as initiation is executed after the injected code. SO you need to execute plain javascript statement.
(Maybe someone can confirm this.)